# How to change where MongoDB saves data

Tags: macos, mongodb

I installed mongodb on my mac but, as I can see now, I installed it using root privileges and it starts on system startup. Whenever I try to change the location of the default data folder using mongod --dbpath I get the following set of errors:

```
[initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
[initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
[websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:48 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
[initandlisten] now exiting
[websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
```

When I run `lsof -i 4 -a` I see that 27017 is used by mongo. The other one is used for web processes of mongo (I assume). I tried to kill the processes by using port number `lsof -i tcp` but it doesn't help. When I try to change path the same thing happens. I don't know what to do at this point because I have to store data on external hard drive.

Comment: Mongodb process is probably managed by `launchd`. You can try `launchctl remove mongod` to stop the running `mongod` process

Comment: no, it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

I finally resolved the issue. I had to stop the process using macports:

```
sudo port unload mongodb
```

and then I ran

```
mongod --dbpath /new/path/
```

Comment: The part that was giving me trouble was how to stop mongodb because I couldn't kill it via terminal. I explained I used mongod --dbpath in the second sentence but the command didn't work because mongo was running. Sorry if it was not clear!

Comment: I assumed that you have already stopped mongodb. Since, you cannot do that operation without stop. This is common thing for all kind of this things like mysql, postgresql, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can give `data` folder path in your `mongo.cfg`

```
path_to_your_mongo_db\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath custom_path\data
```

For full configuration please refer [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#run-mongodb)

**Edit:** For Mac

`mongod --dbpath <some alternate directory>`

You can refer [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#start-mongodb) for full detail

For more configuration, you can have a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600006/how-to-create-a-configuration-file-for-mongodb)

**Important:** `Whether using the default /data/db/ or an alternate directory, ensure that the user account running mongod has read and write permissions to the directory.`

Comment: I don't have cfg file and I am using mac. The point is that mongo starts with the system and once it's started I can't stop it so any of the commands in the tutorial by mongo are not working